# how to replace "opencart" word from back-end

Tags: opencart

i want to replace the "Opencart" word from my back-end by the name of my store. I mean the "Opencart" written before the "Administration" in back end and from its footer in Dashboard. Will please any one help me out?
Thank you..

Answer (score 2):

I think "Opencart" not word but it's an image logo.

You can edit this line :

```
<div class="div2">
   <img src="view/image/logo.png" title="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" onclick="location = '<?php echo $home; ?>'" />
</div>
```

location file : `admin/view/template/common/header.tpl`

Comment: And also look into the `admin/language/YOUR_LANGUAGE/YOUR_LANGUAGE.php` as well as `admin/language/YOUR_LANGUAGE/common/header.php` and `admin/language/YOUR_LANGUAGE/common/footer.php` to possibly remove those `OpenCart` words...

Comment: In your case, yes for remove word on footer (on `language/language1/common/header.php` I can't see "Opencart" word), but OP asking about "Opencart" before "Administration" on back-end (`header.tpl`)